# Can I use Python 3 with default bytes not Unicode?

Tags: python

Is there a systematic way to run Python 3.x with all strings defaulting to bytes? I am finding that when "crossing boundaries" for example talking to msgpack, Elixir, or ZeroMQ, I'm having to do all sorts of contortions constantly figuring out whether strings or bytes will be returned. It's a complete pain and adds a layer of cognitive friction over and above my problem.

For example I have

```
import argparse
parser.add_argument("--nodename")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

and then to get the nodename I need to do

```
str(args.nodename)
```

However zeroMQ wants bytes, and I'm going to use the nodename everywhere I use zeroMQ. So I make it bytes up front with

```
nodename.encode()
```

But now every time I want to use it with a string, say for concatenation, I cannot do so because I have to encode the string first. And half the libraries take perfectly good bytes data type and return them to you as strings, at which time you have to convert them back again to bytes if you want to send them outside Python. For a "glue language" this is a total disaster. I'm having to do this encode decode dance whenever I cross the boundary, and the worst is that it does not seem consistent across libraries whether they co-opt you to strings or bytes if you send them bytes.

In Python 3 is there an option to forego Unicode-by-default (since it does after all say, "by default", suggesting it can be changed), or is the answer "stick with 2.7".

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear since you haven't posted any sample code and output. Have a look at [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) package to see if this fulfils your requirements.

Comment: Needing to mark your byte strings as `bytes` is a feature, and one you will quickly grow accustomed to. Breaking the distinction would cause all kinds of nasty semantics bugs -- I for one *hope* there is no way to do what you're asking.

Comment: @tripleee or we could have done the sensible thing and run UTF8 everywhere, go style, then the problem magically goes away. What a mess.

Comment: Then you'd have the same problem with anything which doesn't use UTF-8 to communicate with you. Perhaps that's currently a smaller problem in practice but not altogether something you can extrapolate into the future for a long-term design.

Comment: @tripleee yeah fair enough. I guess I'm just butting my head against a wall here with converting 2.7 code that's crossing a lot of boundaries but also doing a lot of internal string manipulation and my converted code is getting ugly, fast. Would need a proper refactor to clean it up.

Comment: The `argparse` problem is a valid critique of `argparse` but not really generalizable. I guess I'm not the only one here who thinks `argparse` is clunky and quirky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no. And you *really* don't want to try. You mention contortions but don't give specific examples, so it's hard to offer specific advice.

Neither, in this author's humble opinion, do you want to stick with Python 2.7, but if you don't need bugfixes and language updates after 2020 it won't matter.

The point is precisely that all translation between bytes and text should take place at the boundaries of your code. Decode (from whatever external representation is used) on input, encode (to whatever encoding you wish or need to use) on output. Python 3 is written to enforce this distinction, but understanding the separation should give you proper control and reduce your frustrations.

In Python 3, opening a file in text mode causes `readline` and friends to produce Unicode strings. You can specify the encoding when you open the file if you wish. Opening a file in binary mode causes them to produce bytestrings, to which you will have to apply your own decoding to make sense of them as text.

Whether the Python API for a particular system returns bytes or text is up to its author, and calling Python 3 functions that expect strings with bytestring arguments is likely to lead to confusion and unhappiness. All external communications (network, files, etc.) must necessarily take place in terms of bytestrings, so be clear what is text (decoding on input and encoding on output) and deal with the outside world exclusively in bytestrings.

There are always, of course, difficult corner cases. I don't envy the maintainers of the `email` package, who have to deal with messages containing 6-bit encoded bytestreams themselves potentially containing attachments in multiple different encodings. But then I don't usually have to work in such complex environments, and hopefully neither do you.

Comment: The Python 3.6+ `email` package overhaul actually does a pretty good job of hiding the complexities (though sometimes in unfortunate ways for those of us who understand and work with those complexities).

Comment: Fair enough. You have to admit though that unless I'm doing front end stuff that has unicode requirements for foreign languages, for 99% of data science oriented python this unicode-by-default thing is a pain in the butt. I am fast discovering why the 2.7 transition took so long because this is a non-trivial problem when you're using Python as "glue" between systems but still doing a lot of internal string stuff within Python, because the bytes doesn't have anything like the same amount of string-manipulation support so you're messing with redundant encode decode non stop.

Comment: anyway I do hear you that this is the future so we've got to be disciplined about properly demarcating boundary-access code.

Comment: Sure. Most programmers won't even see the Python 3 mechanisms that produce Unicode from textual input files, and using Unicode does enrich the character set we can all use, as well as avoiding [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). Being in the position of having to glue disparate systems together, not all of which necessarily respect the text/bytes distinction, does mean your work is harder. Good luck!

Comment: PS: if you restrict yourself to 7-bit characters, the `ASCII` encoding works well for string/byes translation, but beware the dreaded `UnicodeError` :-)